# logic: AND and OR statements without parenthesis

Tags: logic, excel-formula

In terms of if conditions in programming languages. I do not remember this stuff so I am asking.

I know what `(A OR B OR (C AND D))` means

but what does `(A OR B OR C AND D)` mean?

Comment: It depends on the programming language and its precedence rules.

Comment: It is not well defined in a language agnostic manner.

Comment: oh okay, excel formulas in powerpivot.

Comment: check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence however in a programming language the precedence may be different than in mathematical logic.

Comment: thanks, good reference. I am going to look at it.

Comment: The real answer to this question is to look in the official documentation for whatever specific language you need to know this about.  It varies, but this is an extremely rudimentary question that would be covered in ANY documentation and in the first or second chapter of any beginner text book for the language in question.

Comment: Excel ***formulas***? They would be using the functions AND() and OR() and the precedence would be determined by the nesting. Or are you talking VBA?

Comment: Ah well, sorry, you are right. The above code was just pseudocode. It uses && and || instead of AND and OR. I used to do some visual basic in SSRS, and the code looks like visual basic in SSRS, but there were no things like && or || in SSRS.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. They are not functions. They are logical operators used between expressions inside the excel formula which will either output true or false. I generalized "excel formula" as the cell that gives output in whatever you enter in a cell, my mistake, I dont know how else to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `AND` takes precedence over `OR`.  But like the comments said, it can depend on the language.  For more information on order of operations, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Another reference, that is Excel specific, also states `AND` precedes `OR` in the order of operations.  See here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080557451.aspx

EDIT:

What this means is that your two statements are equal.

```
(A OR B OR C AND D)
```

is evaluated as:

```
(A OR B OR (C AND D))
```

Comment: thanks, the reference and its examples are helpful too.

Comment: I added another reference that is specific to Excel operator precedence.

Comment: Okay, I guess that is all I need. Thanks for the extra effort.

Comment: Thanks for the edit to clarify for the rest. I forgot to think in terms of calculation based on precedence and used to take the logic all in the same precedence with the help of using parenthesis. Basic algebra that we used to do in high school in terms of precedence (+ - * /) and the links here telling me that I can do that for logical operations helped me to connect the dots.